# If Function using ISTEXT

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I am currently making a little formula to test if a certain cell has certain text, but instead of outputting true and false, I would like it to output "P" or "A".

For some reason, when I use this formula:

```
=IF(ISTEXT(SEARCH("SessionA", D2)), "P", "A")
```

It only outputs "A" for every row and I am not sure what is incorrect with this formula.

Any help would be great, thank you!

Comment: Search returns a number, so it will never be TRUE, Change ISTEXT to ISNUMBER

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(COUNT(SEARCH("SessionA", D4)), "P", "A")
```

I realized I needed to change it to COUNT.
Sorry!